# Confusion about Cantor's theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $P_0, P_1, P_2, ...$ be an enumeration of all one-variable predicates, and let $f(n) = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid P_n(m)\}$. This $f$ isn't surjective since it misses $X = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \not\in f(m)\}$. But isn't "$m \not\in f(m)$" one of the predicates in the enumeration!?

Comment: That's right: $m\notin f(m)$ **isn't** in that enumeration!

Comment: But it can be expressed as a logical formula, which is a finite string of symbols, and finite strings can be enumerated...?

Comment: @John You started by enumerating all the predicates in some language L. Then you added f to the language, giving L'. There's no reason that the original enumeration should include all the predicates in L'.

Answer (score 4):

If your proof seems correct, but contradicts something known (and especially as simple) as Cantor's theorem, it's time to look at your assumptions.

You assume that there is an enumeration of all predicates. So maybe that's the problem? Maybe you've just proved that there isn't any enumeration of *all* predicates. Or maybe the conclusion is false, and simply $\{m\notin f(m)\mid m\in\Bbb N\}$ is not a predicate.

Now. The question is what exactly do you mean by "predicate". If you meant just subsets of $\Bbb N$, well, then there are a lot more subsets. So of course there is no enumeration. But if you mean "predicate" in the sense of a second-order logic kind of object, then we generally have from this that $\{m\notin f(m)\mid m\in\Bbb N\}$ is *not* a predicate, or that $f$ was not a predicate to begin with.

In other words, to be able and *define* a predicate from $f$, you have an implicit assumption that $f$ itself is a definable relation, and that the numeration is somehow definable. In general neither of them is definable, neither is a predicate.

Comment: I know it contradicts Cantor's theorem, but it also seems to contradict the fact that predicates (first-order formulas with one free variable) are countable, which is why I'm asking this question... If we take $m \not\in f(m)$, which is equivalent to $\lnot P_m(m)$, and we apply the definition of $P_m$, don't we get a first order sentence which basically states "$P_m(m)$ is disprovable"? And since this is a first order sentence with one free variable, there should be an $i$ such that $P_i(m)$ is "$P_m(m)$ is disprovable"?

Comment: No. It does not. Why is this enumeration is somehow "inside first order" that you can use it to define a first-order predicate? I think that your misconception runs deep from misunderstanding what it means to be a predicate, and the different between syntax and semantics.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the word predicate wrong, but I just mean "formula with a free variable". And the enumeration is just the enumeration of all finite strings of logical symbols, restricted to valid formulas with a single free variables.

Comment: I think I see what you mean though. So the formula we get doesn't actually state $\lnot P_m(m)$, but rather "there is a sequence of valid logical manipulations to strings of symbols, that gives us the string '$\lnot P_m(m)$'", which is somehow different?

Comment: Yes. So why is the enumeration *part* of FOL? Why can you use it to define a new formula?

Comment: I don't understand why it isn't? A formula is just a string of symbols that respect certain syntactic rules that are expressible in first-order logic. But if I'm understanding correctly, being able to say "we can manipulate strings using these rules to obtain the string $\lnot P_m(m)$" is not the same as saying $\lnot P_m(m)$?

Comment: And the strings come from what set of characters?

Comment: $\{\lnot, \to, \in, \forall, (, ), x_0, x_1, x_2, ...\}$

Comment: $\lnot P_m(m)$ isn't made up of those characters, but by applying the definition of the encoding, and the definition of provability of a formula, we can obtain something made up of just those characters.

Comment: Okay. Please write down to me the predicate that corresponds to the diagonal one.

Comment: It would be an extremely long formula if stated in terms of only those symbols, but basically, it would say: "Let '$A$ is provable' mean there is a sequence $F_0, F_1, ..., F_n$, where $F_0$ contains [strings representing the axioms of set theory], $F_n$ contains the string $A$, and each $F_i$ to $F_{i + 1}$ is one of the following manipulations: [list of string manipulations representing the rules of first order logic]. Then, by letting $P$ be the string whose encoding is $m$, and letting $A$ be $P$ in which we replace $x_0$ with the string representing the number $m$, $A$ is provable"

Comment: Could you please tell me if this is correct: $f$ doesn't miss $X_1 = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \not\in f(m) \text{ is provable}\}$ ("is provable" is just a statement about the existence of a sequence of string manipulations, as described in my last comment), but it does miss $X_2 = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \not\in f(m)\}$. If so, why does $X_1 \neq X_2$?

Comment: You are mixing *so many* things that the only thing I can suggest is to put this aside, read about first-order logic, read about set theory, read about foundations of mathematics, and then find the answer yourself.

Comment: I think I get it. Could you look at the answer I wrote below to see if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's two main misunderstandings.

The first problem is that I'm mixing up the difference between a string of characters which represents a valid formula, and the formula itself. So we do have an enumeration $P_0, P_1, ...$ of strings representing formula, but it doesn't make sense to say $\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid P_n(m)\}$, because "$P_n(m)$" is just a meaningless string, not a formula.

What would make sense, is saying either:

1. $\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid \ulcorner P_n \urcorner(m)\}$, where $\ulcorner F \urcorner$ refers to the actual logical formula encoded by the string $F$. And this solves the problem since this "$\ulcorner F \urcorner$" is something from outside the logic, so it isn't covered by the enumeration.
2. $\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{there's a proof of } P_n(m)\}$, where "proof" is an object listing the sequence of logical manipulations giving the string "$P_n$".

This is where the second problem comes up. The first-order formula expressing "there's a proof of $P_n(m)$" is NOT equivalent to $\ulcorner P_n \urcorner(m)$ itself, because of something called the [incompleteness theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/)! More precisely, $m \not\in f(m)$ says "there is no proof of $P_m(m)$", which is not equivalent to "there is a proof of $\lnot P_m(m)$".